# FullCalendar (Angular 13) installation with npm error

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, npm-install

When running:

```
npm i @fullcalendar/angular
```

I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: mon-premier-projet@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@13.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"~13.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"9 - 12" from @fullcalendar/angular@5.10.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@fullcalendar/angular
npm ERR!   @fullcalendar/angular@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-11-24T12_37_33_454Z-debug.log
```

How do I resolve this? Thanks for the answer

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJ256.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
npm i @fullcalendar/angular --legacy-peer-deps
```

Comment: Presumably they tried that, since it's suggested in the error message. But… I suppose maybe they didn't, since they didn't offer much detail about what they tried?